# How to make image (un-)clickable?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

i am writing an apps that show some picture,and it will call some function when user clicking the image

in portrait mode, i set the image is clickable to preview it in large scale:

```
[imgv addTarget:self action:@selector(funShowPhoto) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and i wish to skip this function when landscape mode, i try this but the function still call, what should i do?

```
[imgv addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add condition in you `funShowPhoto` method

```
-(void)funShowPhoto
{
// check if device is in portrait orientation
  if([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
  {

   // run your code here device is in Portrait Mode

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the code given previously Panayot Panayotov:

```
imgv.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

In that way you don't have to change the action.

Comment: Do this when your device orientation get changed, if landscape set userInteractionEnabled to `NO`else `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UIButton *button_barcord = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  // .....button_faves....
    [button_barcord addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(bMethod:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button_barcord setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimag.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button_barcord setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button_barcord.frame = CGRectMake(240,75,54,54);
    [self.view addSubview:button_barcord];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(IBAction)bMethod:(id)sender
{


}
```